# Base64 encoding/decoding not working with special characters in Java 1.6

Tags: java, encoding, base64, string-decoding

I am using JDK 1.6 and facing issue while trying to encoding/decoding French words. My code is under:

```
String setText = "Vos factures impayées Internet sont";
String encodedText= Base64.encode(setText.getBytes());
Base64.decode(encodedText);
System.out.println("Encoded String: " + encodedText);
byte[] result =  Base64.decode(encodedText);
String decodedString = new String(result);
System.out.println("Decoded: " + decodedString);
```

Result is: 
Original String 
Vos factures impayées Internet sont

Encoded String: Vm9zIGZhY3R1cmVzIGltcGF577+9ZXMgSW50ZXJuZXQgc29udA==

Decoded: Vos factures impay�es Internet sont

Issue: In decoding string i am getting " � " special character instead of "é"

Comment: The program actually thinks your string is `"Vos factures impay�es Internet sont"`, because your source file’s encoding does not match the file encoding assumed by the Java compiler.  My guess is that you saved the file as ISO 8859-1, but the Java compiler is assuming UTF-8 (since UTF-8 is the default encoding on all non-Windows systems).  Make sure you have saved your file as a UTF-8 file.

Comment: No i am not saving this in ISO 8859-1

Comment: A hex dump of the `String setText = "…"` line, performed with an operating system command and not with Java code, would be quite useful.

Answer (score 0):

i do not have java 1.6 but try to specify encoding explicitly not to rely on platform settings, like this. maybe it will help.

```
String decodedString = new String(result, "UTF-8");
```

it will be nice if you share from which package are you using `Base64`and for what reasons? if you are using it with `xml`answer can differ.

Comment: This is only half of the problem.  The Base64 encoding represents bytes that contain an actual `�` character ([U+FFFD](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/fffd/index.htm)) encoded in UTF-8, which indicates the problem was probably due to the encoding assumed by the compiler.  Also, the StandardCharsets class was introduced in Java 1.7, so the code would need to be `new String(result, "UTF-8")`.

Comment: Having the same issue after using 
String decodedString = new String(result, "UTF-8");

I am using the following libraries 
import com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.dv.util.Base64;
import sun.misc.BASE64Encoder;

I am using 1.6 JDK at client level and 1.8 at server level due to some limitations. And in the encoded string i need to pass some url like "https://google.com"

Comment: I'm trying with 1.8 and where I have  `'�'` character in my string, where I'm using  `new String(result, "UTF-8")` but still its not working, where I changed the `UTF-8` to `ISO-8859-1` and its working as expected:)